# why can't I find sqrt using this code?

Tags: java, sqrt

I tried finding a way to get a sqrt without built-ins and came up ith this, unfortunately it won't work and I have no idea why

```
    double num=0;
    while ((num*num)!=this.first)
        num=num+0.0001;
    return num;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ripped from Google:

```
What is floating point error?
The most common situation is illustrated by the decimal number 0.1.
Although it has a finite decimal representation, in binary it has an
infinite repeating representation. Thus when = 2, the number 0.1 lies
strictly between two floating-point numbers and is exactly representable
by neither of them.
```

So, filling in your example of 9, your loop probably looked like:

```
num = 0; add 0.0001 -> num is now 0.000099999999
add 0.0001 -> num is now 0.000199999999998
add 0.0001 -> num is now 0.000299999999997
etc...
add 0.0001 -> num is now 2.9999999999953667
add 0.0001 -> num is now 3.000099999994321
```

And so, your exact comparison to 3 will not match.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to get exact equality.  You might conceivably get within `0.0001` of the true square root, but that's it.  But `num*num` is not going to exactly equal `this.first` unless it's actually a square of a multiple of `0.0001`.

`while ((num * num) < this.first)` would probably be closer to what you want.

Comment: i've tried running it with 9 and didn't get an output, why didn't num become 3 and output it?

Comment: Can you provide the full method/class?

Comment: It probably did not work properly because of how decimal floating point numbers are encoded into binary.  It often has problems just like this.  Using '=' to compare them is not 100% guaranteed.  Instead, you need to compare the difference.   Something like while( abs(this.first - (num*num)) > 0.0001) {...}.     Also, I hope this is a first pass and you will come up with a better algorithm.  This one would take forever if you wanted to come up with the sqrt of 1,000,000.

Comment: well I can't use abs because it's a built in but thanks for the rest of the explanation, helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public class FindSqrt {

public static void main(String[] strings) {

    double num = 3;
    System.out.println(sqrt(num, 0, num));
}


private static double sqrt(double num, double min, double max) {
    if (max-min<=0.0002) min=max;
    double middle = (min + max) / 2;
    double x = middle * middle;
    if ((num>=x&&num-x<=0.02)||(x>=num&&x-num<=0.02)) {
        return middle;
    } else if (x < num) {
        return sqrt(num, middle, max);
    } else {
        return sqrt(num, min, middle);
    }
}
}
```

If you need a solution without recursion (but while loops are OK, the following works):

```
public class FindSqrt {

public static void main(String[] strings) {

    double num = 131072;
    System.out.println(sqrt(num, 0, num));
}


private static double sqrt(double num, double min, double max) {
    boolean done = false;
    double answer = 0;

    while(!done){
        if (max-min<=0.0002) min=max;
        double middle = (min + max) / 2;
        double x = middle * middle;
        if ((num>=x&&num-x<=0.02)||(x>=num&&x-num<=0.02)) {
            done = true;
            answer = middle;
        } else if (x < num) {
            min = middle;
        } else {
            max = middle;
        }
    }
    return answer;



}
}
```

However, in either case, you can use this to find the square root of numbers<=131072

Comment: Using recursion to solve this is a bad idea, considering max double is somewhere around 1.7*10^308.

Comment: Only if you use big enough numbers. I went with the assumption (since built-in Math libraries aren't allowed), that this is a school assignment. You wouldn't really test it with values outside the integer range (again, an assumption). However I do agree that generally recursion would be a bad idea, just not in this particular case.